# poliigon texture is not showing

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, gltf

So I am new to blender, I want to create a flower to show on my web page. I imported a model from the poliigon, and also a texture. The problem is, the texture / colors are not visible when exported, although when rendered in blender, they are. Why is that?
Here is how it looks in blender:
[image]

and this is how it looks in 3d viewer:
[image]

why is this happening?

**EDIT **
this is how the shading part looks for the upper part of the flower:
[image]

Also, I found that if i change just the basecolor[image]:

it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: No, this is not about the object mode or the viewport shading. To sum up, in blender I can see the textures and materials on objects, but if I export them, they are not visible, only the model is

Comment: Hello please show your material, it may not work if exported if it's not compatible with another app

Comment: https://www.poliigon.com/model/plant-orchid-001/5294  this is the model I am importing, but I first noticed this problem while trying to put this material:
https://www.poliigon.com/texture/dirt-window-stains-005/1923
onto a sphere, the sphere had no texture at all, only the sphere model was being exported

Comment: [texturing - .fbx export why there are no materials or textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: Basically, your issue is not in Blender, but in a different application ?

Comment: Basically, my issue is that I do not really understand what is happening. I am not talking about another application, I am talking about the export of the file. I want to understand what is actually happening, and why the textures are not shown. I'm now reading from the link @JohnEason has provided

Comment: Make sure to check that application use of the textures, probably the way the names are written is not the correct way, every App uses different ways to manage textures, because of that, make sure to check that they are all connected or added to the correct area to show them

Comment: @Emir Read through the BSE link I provided which explains exactly why textures using any node except the Principled BSDF one can't be exported!

Comment: @JohnEason as you can see in my question, the texture is linked to a Principled BSDF node. Isn't that what you mean? Or what are you saying is that only the Principled BSDF will be exported?

Comment: Blender Nodes and any procedural textures made with the nodes are proprietary. you can't export the nodes, the only two ways (as far as i know, maybe there are more ways) that i know to export procedural materials is to UV unwrap your mesh and Bake the materials or using a cycles pluggin/bridge available for that application.

Comment: @DragosPolifronie As that answer I linked to says, the Principled BSDF node is the **only** one that can be exported. Any other nodes (which include nodes linked to it)  will not be exported because the export file formats don't have the means to export them. The applications they're being imported into wouldn't understand Blender's node system anyway.

Comment: @JohnEason that makes sense, what I don't understand in fact is, why, for example, the node that gives the color, is exported? Like if I get the COLOR part from a texture imported from poliigon, and link that to the Principled BSDF color, the color is, indeed exported together with the model, making it visible in other applications ( default windows 3D viewer for example )

Comment: @DragosPolifronie I don't know the technical details I'm afraid.

Comment: If you're exporting to .gltf or .glb, there's a detailed document on which inputs to Principled BSDF the exporter can convert into glTF materials: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html. In general, it's one texture per socket.